# OpenLayers 3 - Custom Image Url

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I want to get an image thanks to a custom url, because I send a servlet request to my server.

With OL2, I set `this.url` in `OpenLayers.Layer.WMTS` when `singleTile` was true.

Today in OL3, I created a subclasse of ol.source.Image where I change the method `getRequestUrl_`
It works fine with the openlayers-debug build, but when I want to make my own custom build of openlayers, I get an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.jb is not a function
```

I guess there is something missing in my own build. I exported ol.Image, maybe ol.ImageBase is missing : `No matching symbol found: ol.ImageBase`

So, if you know a proper way to do it, or explain me where am I wrong.
Thank you !

PS: Do you know if [online-builder](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/builder/) of Openlayers will be "online" again ?

Comment: Actually, the problem shows up when I use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS for my build. It works fine with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.

Comment: All methods finishing with `_` are private and aren't available in the minified build file.

Comment: Ok, so do you know how can I get around this problem ? Is it possible to configure my url not in private context ?

Comment: Your question is not clear (at least for me). Try to resume it to a single point.

Comment: I want to use my own custom url to request the image (not static).